# Python Web Frameworks For Production Level

Tags: python

I  have been using Flask for Building REST API on the development level. I want to create REST API at Production Level. So which Python web framework would be Best?

These frameworks I saw while searching:

```
CherryPy
Flask
Django
Pyramid
TurboGears
Pylons
Web2py
Falcon
Bottle
Etc.
```

Comment: Why not use flask for production also? Ref: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/structuring-a-flask-restplus-web-service-for-production-builds-c2ec676de563

Comment: @Abhijith Mg I don't know because I am still under training on Flask and don't know much about other's so. And I have to start working on Production level soon so I want to Learn about which web framework would be best if Not FLask Then?

Comment: why to start learning Flask and thinking about using something else on prod? Its like finish learning to drive a car and then think how to provide a helicopter.

Comment: @ Chiefir So i can Use Flask also at Production level and Django also Right?

Comment: @Raj Pandey you can use all of them on prod - it depends on your purposes. If you are heavily depended on database relations - better choice is Django, if you want to write simple API - Flask is much more easy. All another frameworks are some kind of niche. And you are should use them if you exactly know why u want to use them.

Comment: Thank you so much, Now  I understand it. @ Chiefir

Comment: Flask IS used daily on production by quite a few sites / apps.

Comment: Ok so if i want to store my Data in MSSQL or MongoDB i can Do it with it. I can also use SQLAlchamy to generate .db files.

SO here's my question Which is good for production of REST API? is it with traditional Databases or with SQLAlchmy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has a big support for REST API. According to my own experience I'd advice Django.

See more here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Ok, so other than Flask and Django we don't have much of a choice?

Comment: I should go for Django REST framework right? is Django and Django REST Framework are Different things or we can use Django to build REST? I am Confused a Little.

Comment: @Raj Pandey DRF - is some kind of add-on for Django to write APIs. You can't use it without Django.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my queries. Really appreciated it. @Chiefir

Comment: Ok so if i want to store my Data in MSSQL or MongoDB i can Do it with it. I can also use SQLAlchamy to generate .db files. SO here's my question Which is good for production of REST API? is it with traditional Databases or with SQLAlchmy

Comment: @RajPandey I think you should post this as another question to see more answers

Answer (score 0):

For a REST API, I would use [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/).  It has a strong reputation.

I have used it for several projects, and I like it because it fairly easily lets you *do the right thing* without much work.  For instance, it relies upon `pedantic` to ensure the proper data types for what you are sending/receiving.